# answers Average case analysis of linear search

Tags: time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

Suppose we have an array$[1..n]$ and run linear search to find $x$, on it with following specification:
probability of existence $x$ in first half of array is $p$,and probability of existence $x$ in second half is $3p$ and in each half probability of any element to be x is equally likely.Calculate Average case linear search.
Is my answer true?

$E[successful]+unsuccessful=\sum_{i=1}^{n/2}pi + \sum_{i=\frac{n}{2}+1}^{n}3pi + (1-p)(1-3p)n $

Comment: Do I correctly understand, that last summand is for the case when we did not find the required $x$?

Comment: Yes.it for we did not find the required x

Comment: The events "the element is not in the first half" and "the element is not in the second half" are not independent, you can't just multiply their probabilities.

Comment: According to this comment what we do?

Comment: The event $F$ "an element is not found is" is the complement of the event "an element is found" which is the union of the events $A$ "an element is found in the first half" and $B$ "an element is found in the second half". Since $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, the probability of $A \cup B$ is $\Pr(A)+P(B)=p+3p=4p$, hence $\Pr(F) =1-P(A \cup B) =1-4p$

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.